# How to design layout in Action Script 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to design a registration form using only ActionScript, i have designed labels and text boxes but using label.x = "10" label.y="40" text.x = "50" text.y ="40"... to align correctly.
But i want to design a layout such that all labels and text boxes will be aligned properly.
Any Help or examples or Docs ?

Comment: If you're using Flash...either you align the components manually...or use something like MinimalComps(minimalcomps.com) for the HBox/VBox ...or try the Yahoo! Form components(http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/form/)...Depending on the scale of your project...you could have a stab at the Flex framework...Forms components are just a few of the many out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flex you can use HBox/VBox and set dimensions in percent. Otherwise you could create a helper class (like PositionUtils) that could help you out.

```
// position the displayobjects in list with margins 0, 5 and 10
PositionUtils.alignVertical([txtHeader,txtBody, btnSend], [0,5,10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in AS3 only, without frameworks , you may consider creating your own components.

You could create a FormField class , which would at the minimum contain a TextField for the label, and a TextField for the text input. Create a params setters , which would help you customize various aspects such as the margin between the label & the textInput, text colors, background color, font , textformat etc...

For a registration form , create several fields and you'll simply have to set either the x or the y value for each field & they will naturally align.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AS3Commons UI Layouts](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-ui/layouts/). This is a pure AS3 library I am developing exactly for that purpose.